# Kubernetes Distributed testing - Jmeter won't start; sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPConnection close

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, distributed

My architecture: namespaces in kubernetes behind proxy, firewall and other switches.
My master sends tasks to the slaves and when the script ends, it closes the slaves and the master. I have netpols, ingress and egress configured and running. I have open ports in the 3-port ranges, e.g. 60000-60002, 1099-1101.

My problem: Normally, when I start a test, the master should send logs such as :

```
"Oct 12, 2022 11:31:39 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /mount/10_2022/scenario.jmx
Configuring remote engine: slave-1
Using local port: 60000
Starting distributed test with remote engines: [slave-1] @ October 12, 2022 11:31:41 AM CEST (1665567101036)
Remote engines have been started:[opl-jmeter-distributed-slave-1]
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445"
```

While the master sends logs :

```
"Oct 12, 2022 11:31:39 AM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
INFO: Created user preferences directory.
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /mount/10_2022/scenario.jmx
Configuring remote engine: slave-1
Using local port: 60000
Starting distributed test with remote engines: [slave-1] @ October 12, 2022 11:31:41 AM CEST (1665567101036)
```

**<Between this lines is about 7-10 minutes break.>**

```
"Remote engines have been started:[opl-jmeter-distributed-slave-1]
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445"
```

nothing happens after that, except log errors like :

```
"2022-10-12 11:40:30,274 ERROR o.a.j.s.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) on slave-1
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: <MASTER'S IP>; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)"
```

and

```
"2022-10-12 11:49:18,668 ERROR o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: sampleOccurred
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: <MASTER'S IP>; nested exception is:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)"
```

I started debugging my actions and this is what I get from the master logs:

```
"Oct 13, 2022 10:45:37 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel free
FINE: RMI RenewClean-[172.16.28.15:60000,SSLRMIClientSocketFactory(keyStoreLocation=/mount/keyStore/rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=/mount/keyStore/rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi)]: create reaper
Oct 13, 2022 10:45:52 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel$1 run
FINER: RMI Scheduler(0): wake up
Oct 13, 2022 10:45:52 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel freeCachedConnections
FINER: RMI Scheduler(0): connection timeout expired
Oct 13, 2022 10:45:52 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPConnection close
FINE: RMI Scheduler(0): close connection"
```

I started debugging my actions and this is what I get from the master logs:

```
Oct 13, 2022 10:45:37 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel free
FINE: RMI RenewClean-[172.16.28.15:60000,SSLRMIClientSocketFactory(keyStoreLocation=/mount/keyStore/rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=/mount/keyStore/rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi)]: create reaper
Oct 13, 2022 10:45:52 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel$1 run
FINER: RMI Scheduler(0): wake up
Oct 13, 2022 10:45:52 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel freeCachedConnections
FINER: RMI Scheduler(0): connection timeout expired
Oct 13, 2022 10:45:52 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPConnection close
FINE: RMI Scheduler(0): close connection
```

Please help. Any clue? Why my test doesn't start?

**--- UPDATE ---**

***My slave yaml:***

```
> apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jmeter-distributed-slave-1
  labels:
    run: jmeter-slave
  namespace: tst-eff
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    name: debug
  - port: 60000
    name: input
  - port: 1099
    name: port
  selector:
    id: jmeter-distributed-slave-1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jmeter-distributed-slave-1
  labels:
    run: jmeter-slave
    layer: slave
    type: distributed
    id: jmeter-distributed-slave-1
  namespace: tst-eff
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: jmeter-distributed-slave-1
    image: performance/jmeter:5.5
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    env:
    - name: JVM_ARGS
      value: "-server -d64 -Xms12g -Xmx31g -Xss256k -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 60000
    - containerPort: 8000
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mount"
      name: properties
    - mountPath: "/users"
      name: users
    command: ["jmeter.sh"]
    args: ["-s", "-Jserver.rmi.localport=60000", "-Jserver.rmi.ssl.keystore.file=/mount/keyStore/rmi_keystore.jks", "-Jhttpclient4.retrycount=1", "-Jhttpclient4.idletimeout=5000", "-Jhttp.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true", "-q", "/mount/prod.properties", "-D", "javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/mount/keyStore/keystore_prod.jks", "-D", "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=passwordpassword", "-j", "/mount/logs_jmeter/jmeter-distributed-slave-1_'YYYYMMdd_HHmm'.log"]
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 2
        memory: 12G
      limits:
        cpu: 3
        memory: 30G
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: credentials
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: xxx
  volumes:
  - name: properties    
    nfs:
      server: xxx.xx.xx.xx
      path: /performance_tst_eff/jmeter/
  - name: users
    nfs:
      server: yyy.yy.yy.yy
      path: /performance_tst_eff/jmeter-1-r1
```

***My master yaml:***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jmeter-distributed-master
  labels:
    run: jmeter-master
  namespace: tst-eff
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    name: debug
  - port: 60000
    name: input
  - port: 1099
    name: port
  selector:
    id: jmeter-distributed-master
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jmeter-distributed-master
  labels:
    run: jmeter-master
    type: distributed
    layer: master
    id: jmeter-distributed-master  
  namespace: tst-eff
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: jmeter-distributed-master
    image: performance/jmeter:5.5
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    env:
    - name: UMASK
      value: "011"
    - name: JVM_ARGS
      value: "-server -d64 -Xms1g -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 60000
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mount"
      name: properties
    - mountPath: "/users"
      name: users
    command: ["bash"]
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 4G
      limits:
        cpu: 4
        memory: 8G
    args: ["-c", "/jmeter/bin/jmeter.sh -n -Jserver.rmi.localport=60000 -Jserver.rmi.ssl.keystore.file=/mount/keyStore/rmi_keystore.jks -Jclient.tries=3 -Jclient.retries_delay=10000 -Ghttpclient4.retrycount=1 -Ghttpclient4.idletimeout=5000 -Ghttp.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true -D javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/mount/keyStore/keystore_prod.jks -D javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=passwordpassword -q /mount/prod.properties -l /mount/results/mini_smoke_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).jtl -t /mount/10_2022/mini.jmx -j /mount/logs_jmeter/jmeter-distributed-master_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).log -R jmeter-distributed-slave-1 -X"]
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: credentials
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: xxxx
  volumes:
  - name: properties
    nfs:
      server: xxx.xx.xx.xx
      path: /performance_tst_eff/jmeter/
  - name: users
    nfs:
      server: yyy.yy.yy.yy
      path: /performance_tst_eff/jmeter-1-r1
```

Where is wrong?
The following ports I have open on the firewall:
1099-1101
8000-8002
60000-60002

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. My firewall did not allow connection between slave and master on [ephemeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) ports. The slave wants to communicate with the master on ephemeral ports and when I opened those ports, everything starts working.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your [RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) is not correct

You need to create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and expose the following ports:

- `1099` or whatever is your `server_port`
- `4000` or whatever is your `server.rmi.localport`

Like in the Dockerfile for the slave:

```
EXPOSE 1099 4000
```

In k8s service YAML

```
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 1099
      name: server_port
      targetPort: 1099
    - port: 4000
      name: server_rmi_localport
      targetPort: 4000
```

And do the same for the `client.rmi.localport` on JMeter master side.

More information: [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker)

Comment: I use k8s yaml and I have service. I creating service and pod in one yaml, like this: 

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: slave-1
  labels:
    run: jmeter-slave
  namespace: <ns_name>
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    name: debug
  - port: 60000
    name: input
  - port: 1099
    name: port
  selector:
    id: slave-1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: slave-1
  labels:`

and so on.

Comment: could you take a look at my update and tell me where the error / bug is?